# JAXB - StringWriter trims the value on String conversion but prints whole xml string in console

Tags: java, rabbitmq, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to convert java object into XML string to pass the string value to RabbitMQ queue. But while i do so, i use StringWriter to Print XML String to Console and also Write XML to StringWriter. Below is my code snippet

```
//Create JAXB Context
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(BiothenticateABCWSRequest.class);
             
            //Create Marshaller
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
 

            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            
            //Print XML String to Console
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
             
            //Write XML to StringWriter
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(biothenticateABCWSRequest, sw);
             
            //Verify XML Content
            xmlContent = sw.toString();
            System.out.println( xmlContent);
```

**Image-1**
[image]

**Image-2**
[image]

**Image-3**
[image]

above i am facing problem with StringWriter. when i convert StringWriter sw object into string object xmlContent and return it, it trims the returned xml values and the same string object xmlContent prints the complete values in console.

Ex: in **Image-1** i have object from method args which has its populated value and **Image-2** you can StringWriter sw object has trimmed values in end  like `...`.
But in **Image-3** its the printed StringWriter sw object values in console. Here you can see it has its complete values.

**without trim** string object xmlContent length in console is 2,32,442

**with trim** returned string object xmlContent length is 10,009.

I do not understand why StringWriter can not return complete xml value from object after marshalling in `xmlContent = sw.toString();`.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Not very sure about the question, please post more code to describe the problem in detail.

Comment: @SariqShaikh i have pasted complete code, now you can see the details from pictures.